# CSS background-image repeat on hover over anchor tag

Tags: html, css, macos, image

I am having a problem with this specifically on macs, and most recently I was having a bolder font problem with only macs as well, but that had been fixed via CSS.

**Problem:** I have 10 anchor tags absolute positioned, and when on hover (green background-image), there isn't any overlap problems on a PC, but on a Mac in almost every browsers, the background-image overlaps a little into the next sentence.

[image]

**CSS for above (hover):**

```
.homeText a:hover {

    background-image: url('/cont-img/on-hover-span_background-partial-solid.jpg');
    color: White;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    margin-right:-5px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

The CSS absolute positioning of each element has plenty of space between the sentences, so that isn't an issue. Also, the period at the end is a sprite of 2 different images, a white period on hover, and a grey period off hover. For this, I append a css class to the span tag at the end of the anchor tag that sets the background-position for the sprite in the span tag.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Would be nice to have a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to reroduce your situation. What happens when you add `overflow:hidden` to the anchors ? Why would you use an image for a solid color background when you can simply use `background-color` ?

Comment: i need a certain color to match the corresponding image banner, and since it happens to be no where close to a web safe color, a background-image of a solid color is the only other solution. I will try overflow hidden. I think that the problem is that when the anchor becomes italicized, the length increases.

Comment: You say you use absolute positioning, is that right? Then how are you positioning your anchors? I mean, how do you know where to put them?

Comment: i'm simply using top (and right on the second sentences) on each individual case id# in CSS.

Comment: What browsers did you test? Did you try the same browser (and version number) on the Mac as on the PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have a span tag inside of each anchor, I realized that I had to, with the help of Timmerz, remove padding and margin-right from each case. The most significant reason I was getting more background-image overlap than expected is because the width of the span was unnecessarily big for the amount of pixels the period only takes up, creating more space for overlapping.

After setting the spans to a width proportional to the picture in the sprites, I added a little padding right so the background-image didn't tug too close to the sprite. Also, I had to adjust my absolute position on the right cases because of the adjustments stated above.

Thanks for everyone's contribution.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have `padding:0; margin:0;` and make sure the `<a>` does not contain a space or something after the period. also, why are you using a background image? can't you just set the `background-color:green`?...which you might want to try just to see if it's any different.

Comment: i need a certain color to match the corresponding image banner, and since it happens to be no where close to a web safe color, a background-image of a solid color is the only other solution. I can try removing margin and just changing by absolute positioning. I'll let you know how that goes.

Comment: The problem I think I am having is that i have a span tag at the end of each anchor, and the span tag doesn't generate any space inside the anchor tag. So if I was just to use just absolute positioning, without any margin and padding on the span CSS, the span wouldn't appear.

Comment: yeah, I think you nailed it. the background image would include the span, no? you might want to use firebug or chrome developer and go to to the span and see the default css applied by the browser stylesheets.

Comment: i'm using chromes dev tool, and I got the background to align close to the period, but too close.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's just a font issue. When I visit your site in Linux, the links have much more space between them than in Windows.

By the way, maybe a bit off topic, but your site doesn't handle non-white background colours very well. You may want to set the background color yourself, rather than rely on the user's default.

Comment: it's a background-image, not a color. therefore i am rendering the "color" myself. The problem I think I am having is that i have a span tag at the end of each anchor, and the span tag doesn't generate any space inside the anchor tag. So if I was just to use just absolute positioning, without any margin and padding, the span wouldn't appear.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but I should have posted all of my CSS :-/

Comment: No, I mean the background color of the site itself, which you leave set to the user's preference, while the text on it is dark gray. That clashes. Use `body {background-color:white}`.

Comment: i do have the body background-color set to white in my CSS.

Comment: Oh... not in the online version of your site though. If you set the background color to #BBBBBB in your browser's default settings, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: okay, thanks for that fix :) (you won't see if because it's in staging)